# How do I get my iCal feed to show past events?

Tags: civievent

How do I get the iCal feed that displays as html at 
`/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&html=1` 
or as a feed at `/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1` to show past events?

Using Wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the param `&start=YYYYMMDD`

On the html side use `civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&start=20070101&html=1`

on the ical side use `/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&start=20070101`

In that example 20070101 is January 1st 2007 - you can change the date to whatever you would like.